# The toolbar not show icon. the text changed his color and toolbar altered his height in Android-Ionic 4

Tags: android, icons, toolbar, ionic4, capacitor

I'm developing a simple app using ionic 4 with angular, when I compiled with capacitor and run in android, the toolbar changed. Not show correctly. The text change white for black, the trash icon not show and the height of the toolbar increase. Other functions works correctly

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/recipes"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>recipe-detail</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button (click)="onDeleteRecipe()"><ion-icon name="trash" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon></ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

the toolbar should have white text and trash icon

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code in a repo?

Comment: this is the repo: https://gitlab.com/javierac87/simple-ionic4-project

Comment: I ran it with capacitor and can see the white trash can - no black text.

Comment: Can you tell me what versions of capacitor, angular cli, android SDK and ionic cli did you use, exactly? please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repo works as expected, here is my info:

```
Ionic:
   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.2.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1

Capacitor:
   capacitor (Capacitor CLI) : 1.0.0-beta.19
   @capacitor/core           : 1.0.0-beta.19

Cordova:
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : none
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/jayordway/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   NodeJS            : v10.14.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.2 Build version 10E125
```